# Dynamically Creating Icons in Lightning Design System

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am trying to dynamically create buttons to with an icon on them on a Visualforce page using the Lightning Design system.  If I hardcode the HTML into the page, everything shows up as expected.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--icon">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Lightning_Design, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}"></use>
  </svg>
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Settings</span>
</button>
```

[image]

This shows up as a delete/trashcan icon at the top of my page.  I also use javascript in order to create a series of these inside of a table based upon records in the database.

```
var tableBody = dataTable.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))
                                var dataRow, dataRowCell1, dataRowCell2, dataRowCell3, actionCell, recordName, fieldName, mpName, actionButton, delSvg, useLink, delSpan;
records.forEach(function(record)
{
  dataRow = tableBody.insertRow();

  dataRowCell1 = dataRow.insertCell(0);
  recordName = document.createTextNode(record.get('Name'));
  dataRowCell1.appendChild(recordName);

  dataRowCell2 = dataRow.insertCell(1);
  fieldName = document.createElement('input');
  fieldName.setAttribute('id', record.get('Id') + 'FieldName');
  fieldName.value = record.get('Field_Name__c');
  dataRowCell2.appendChild(fieldName);

  dataRowCell3 = dataRow.insertCell(2);
  mpName = document.createElement('input');
  mpName.setAttribute('id', record.get('Id') + 'MPName');
  mpName.value = record.get('MP_Name__c');
  dataRowCell3.appendChild(mpName);

  //Below here is the main code for this question.
  actionCell = dataRow.insertCell(3);
  actionButton = document.createElement('button');
  actionButton.setAttribute('class', 'slds-button slds-button--icon');

  delSvg = document.createElement('svg');
  delSvg.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
  delSvg.setAttribute('class', 'slds-button__icon');

  useLink = document.createElement('use');
  useLink.setAttribute("xlink:href", "{!URLFOR($Resource.Lightning_Design, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}");
  useLink.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
  delSvg.appendChild(useLink);
  actionButton.appendChild(delSvg);

  delSpan = document.createElement('span');
  delSpan.setAttribute('class', 'slds-assistive-text');
  delSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Settings'));
  actionButton.appendChild(delSpan);

  actionCell.appendChild(actionButton);
});
```

For whatever reason the icon doesn't show up on these tables rows.  I inspected the html at both locations and it turns up **exactly** the same.  They are both also enclosed inside of the required SLDS wrapper so that also isn't the issue.  In the below table, the icon should be showing up to the right of the other fields.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue just by dynamically creating a button which contains SVG tag inside it using javascript.Strangely the dynamic button markup while inspecting the element was same as the static ones included in the page(as you described in the question).

Few trail and errors, I found that the **DOM API** `appendChild()` behaved strangely only for SVG elements.

```
 actionButton.appendChild(delSvg); // Not working if child is svg
```

So I tried to set the **innerHTML** of the button tag to the SVG's HTML content and it solved the issue.

Here's what I tried:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <body class="slds" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS202, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Settings</span>
        </button>

     <div id="svgBtn"/>

   </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var svgLink = "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS202, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}";
        var delSvg = document.createElementNS ("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            delSvg.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
            delSvg.setAttribute('class', 'slds-button__icon');

        var useLink = document.createElement('use');
            useLink.setAttribute("xlink:href",svgLink);
            useLink.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
            delSvg.appendChild(useLink);


        var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
            button.setAttribute('class', 'slds-button slds-button--icon');
            button.innerHTML = delSvg.outerHTML;

        document.getElementById("svgBtn").appendChild(button);

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at this in a little bit.  It sounds like it could be promising.

Comment: This worked, I can award the bounty tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

I see you are creating a VF page - this is quite different. 
Since you are creating SVG, this is essentially a different namespace, so you would create an element as follows.

First, define a div to append the svg element to:

```
<div id="svgContainer"/>
```

Then in call this in JavaScript:

```
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var boxWidth = 100;
var boxHeight = 100;

var element = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
element.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
element.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
element.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
element.style.display = "block";

var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgContainer");
svgContainer.appendChild (element);
```

---

Original Answer (might still be useful if you are using Lightning)

I suggest you use the custom SVG provided by Lightning [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/). It shows you how you can dynamically specify all the parameters of an SVG, using a component.

I think your specific issue is linked to how lightning renders components, so the key is probably here, in the renderer:

```
// Calls the helper function to append the SVG icon
helper.renderIcon(component);
return ret;
```